# Swift override static method compile error

Tags: swift, static, compilation, compiler-errors

I have these two swift classes:

```
class A {    
    static func list(completion: (_ result:[A]?) -> Void) {
        completion (nil)
    }        
    static func get(completion: (_ result:A?) -> Void) {
        completion (nil)
    }
}


class B: A {    
    static func list(completion: (_ result:[B]?) -> Void) {
        completion (nil)
    }    
    static func get(completion: (_ result:B?) -> Void) {
        completion (nil)
    }        
}
```

Trying to compile this raise the error "overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword" but just for the 'get' method of class B. 'list' method compiles fine. What is the difference between [B]? and B? for the compiler in this case?

Edit: Also notice that adding 'override' is not possible. I get the error 'Cannot override static method'.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In class `B`, the method `list` is a separate method from `list` in class `A`. They just share the same name, that's all.

The parameters of the two `list` methods are actually different:

```
// A.list
static func list(completion: (_ result:[A]?) -> Void) {
// B.list
static func list(completion: (_ result:[B]?) -> Void) {
```

`A.list` takes an argument of type `(_ result: [A]?) -> Void` while `B.list` takes a `(_ result: [B]?) -> Void`. The array type in the closure type's parameter list is different!

So you're not overridding anything, you're just overloading.

Note:

`static` methods can never be overridden! If you want to override a method, use `class` instead of `static`.

```
class A {
    class func get(completion: (_ result:A?) -> Void) {
        completion (nil)
    }
}


class B: A {
    override class func get(completion: (_ result:B?) -> Void) {
        completion (nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. And why is not the same case with the 'get' method?  B.get takes an angument of type B? and A.get of type A?

Comment: Oh I forgot to explain that! Well, it's basically how the "whether this method overrides another method" algorithm is implemented. The algorithms just think that arrays are incompatible types while subclasses and superclasses are compatible types @dce

Answer (score 3):

In short, as per rule, `static methods` can't be overridden.